# Setting axis labels globally for a Jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have several plots in a Jupyter notebook. They are analyzing the same dataset in different ways. I am having to write this line of code repeatedly for those graphs `ax.set(ylabel='No.of Clients')`. How can I set this as a global value for all plots in my notebook?

Comment: Essentially, you can't. But sure nothing is really impossible. So one "option" is to subclass the matplotlib axes such that it always initializes with the given label. Would you consider this a valid solution that would be worth giving an answer for?